# Como ver documentos de la paquetería Microsoft online en ASP.net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, c#-8.0

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web que gestiona documentos de un departamento, en este caso necesito que en la pagina los archivos se guarden en un directorio de mi servidor, algo que ya realizo, posterior a eso necesito mostrarlos al hacerle clic a un boton, lo cual funciona pero solamente con archivos PDF, al parecer con mis archivos .docx, .pptx etc, solamente con los PDF puedo mostrarlos.

Este es el codigo que estaba usando para mostrarlo.

*Codigo .cs*

```
 protected string GetFileUrl()
    {
        string relativeFilePath = "~/Documento/Prueba1.pptx";
        
        // Ruta relativa del archivo dentro de tu solución
        string filePath = Server.MapPath(relativeFilePath);
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath).ToLower();
        string fileContentType = GetContentType(fileExtension);

        byte[] fileBytes;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            fileBytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        }

        string base64File = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
        string fileUrl = "data:" + fileContentType + ";base64," + base64File;
        return fileUrl;
    }

    protected string GetContentType(string fileExtension)
    {
        switch (fileExtension)
        {
            case ".pdf":
                return "application/pdf";
            case ".docx":
                return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
            case ".pptx":
                return "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";
            default:
                return "application/octet-stream";
        }
    }
```

*Codigo aspx*

```
<div>
        <!-- Botón para abrir el modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Abrir archivo PPTX</button>

        <!-- Modal para mostrar el archivo PPTX -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Visor de PPTX</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="iframe-container">
                             <iframe src="<%= GetFileUrl() %>" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0;"></iframe>
                          

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Este es mi boton que abre el modal donde se mira mi documento]

[image: Imagen del pdf mostrado en el modal]

[image: Imagen mostrando un documento pptx]

En la imagen anterior es el intento con un documento pptx que no se muestra

[image: Datos del pptx en mi iframe]

Pero en esta imagen segun entiendo si esta recibiendo la data, pero no es mostrada en mi modal

[image: Libreria que estoy utilizando para mostrarlos]

Finalmente esta es la libreria que estoy usando para mostrar el pdf

Comment: Parece una pregunta adecuada para el soporte de la biblioteca que usas. Has intentado con ellos?